# How to get rid of white alpha outline on images as planes? (Eevee)

Tags: transparency, image

I'm using *Clip Studio Paint* to draw and then export my drawings to pngs in order to animate them in Blender. Every time I do it I have the same issue of this white pixel border around my image's lineart. Blender can see the alpha correctly in UV editor but not in viewport shading. Outline shows on renders as well (I use Eevee).

I've tried fixing it with alpha clip and then it just looks very bad and loses image's details. What can I do to fix it? Maybe export it in a different format?

Clip Studio viewport:
[image]

Blender alpha clip:
[image]

Blender UV comparison:
[image]

Skull PNG:
[image]

Comment: Without knowing your image it is not 100% sure to tell, but you have set the _Blend Mode_ to _Alpha Clip_ with a _Clip Threshold_ of 0.5, which means alpha values up to 0.5 will be completely transparent, everything above will be completely opaque. So if the object has a smoothed outline and alpha channel, an alpha value of for example 0.6 will be fully opaque. And if the image there is white or light grey, it will show up. So you have to either increase the _Clip Threshold_ (probably very high close to 1) or switch the mode to _Alpha Hashed_ or _Alpha Blend_. Or paint the image black there.

Comment: I've played around with threshold values and all it does is make the image unpleasant to look at, it loses lots of details and looks weird. I've seen people on youtube having no issues with their pngs, even when they were a bit blurry etc. they didn't have to mess around with alpha thresholds.

I've tried different alpha's too, hashed and blend, it changes nothing. I think it may be a problem with exporting the image? I don't have Photoshop, I think I have Gimp installed though.

Comment: First of all, did all the other people having no issues use _Eevee_ or _Cycles_? Because in _Cycles_ you will have less problems. Yeah, I realized the other blend modes won't work either and maybe not even in _Cycles_. The problem is, the border has to be painted black. I assume, it has originally a white background where now is transparency. Which means, semi-transparent areas are white/light grey, not black. And they are not completely transparent, so the white color will show up. Because when you have an image, make parts of it transparent and save it, the transparent part is still there.

Comment: They were using either Eevee or Cycles, I was watching this video here https://youtu.be/ChqSqDGCTRA?si=ZWmVAcby1NIAR-Ld

My original image was not painted on a white bg, I was drawing on transparent bg already and exported it as such. The only program that has problems with pngs exported from Clip Studio is Blender so far as using After Effects for example was fine. I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your PNG file has premultiplied alpha, you need to tell Blender that:

[image]

Keep all other settings default (*Blend Mode: Alpha Blend*)

Comment: Thank you @markusvonbroady ! How do I enable the alpha tab? Im using Blender 3.1.0 ![link to screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jTzzUnKe4EtdXRkej6hdhkWr8E1am7o0/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @JeeJeeGamer in that version you would need to convert the image, I think you can do it in Blender, open the png as one type and save it as another, but I haven't done it myself in Blender.